# MySql Performance: INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE or UPDATE & ROW_COUNT

Tags: mysql, performance

I query that most of the times will be updating an existing record.
However, I need to check if this records exists and if not I should create it.

Usually I would use `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDAT`, but as only a few queries will need to insert I was thinking of doing an `UPDATE` and latter checking with if the `ROW_COUNT()` returned is zero and doing an `INSERT` in this case.

What would give me the best performance?

Comment: I think you should give it a try. The unique key lookups will be performed in either way, the first choice (`INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDAT`) would be slightly better. Please try it with tens of thousands of records and come back with the results. It'll just take a few minutes. :)

Comment: Actually I worked it around by sending a flag from the application to indicate a new record. This will have the best performance for sure :)
I'll try to give it a try as you suggested later.
But if the unique check will be done anyway, this should indeed have a better performance than update and row_cound. Thank you!

Comment: Beware when trusting flags from your app: if multiple users are using the same app concurrently, the flags may become invalid the moment one of the users adds a record! Better use the `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` approach. By the way do you really need to worry about performing this query? It probably only really affects performance if doing a LOT of these queries.

Comment: I do it a LOT in my ajax app. So it is important for me.
Regarding the flag issue and users sharing, I do not allow to login to the same account from multiple computers/browsers and block this. But thanks for your comment as this is something that should be taken into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has a REPLACE INTO syntax that could be what you are looking for.  If that doesn't work for you, using UPDATE and checking ROW_COUNT() should work, you might want to wrap that whole thing in a stored proc so you save yourself a trip back to the server.